# Finding start and end tags in string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to parse an HTML file ( non strict one) using JavaScript

my output should be the same HTML file, but I need to process the internal content of any `<script></script>` tag. I have a method `processScript(script)` that does that..

I can assume that there will be no `<script/>` tags.

I have a pretty clear idea how to it using just `split()` but I wonder if I can do it better using regex?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing HTML with Regex is generally not the best way to do it. Look into DOM parsing instead, using methods like `getElementsByName('script')` and such. I'd also suggest looking at the w3schools examples on [HTML DOM Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) to get you started in the right direction.

There are a lot of reasons why this is a better approach, a few of them being that 1) Javascript has this DOM Object support already, and it is much easier than using Regex and 2) The language of matching open/close tags (similar to matching parens/brackets/etc) is not a regular language.

Comment: w3schools is nothing to do with the W3C.

Comment: Bleh, that was what I meant. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: what would I do with HTML pages that aren't exactly following the XML rules? would it still work? I am running my JS script outside a browser..

Comment: How are they not "following the rules"? Do you mean that they are not valid XML/HTML? If you search SO for your question, you'll find lots of posts that explain ways to parse HTML without using regex, and possibly one that fits your specific situation.